# SwiftUI asking for enormous quantity of RAM?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I've been testing SwiftUI for my team's future endeavors, and occasionally my Mac's fan will get really noisy, and it will heat up a lot. I usually have a few Xcode editors open but I never run more than one simulator at a time. After looking at the Activity Monitor, I noticed that a process called "SourceKitService" was asking for 87 GB of RAM! This is obviously impossible for any Mac to run, so I'm starting to think that it is unexpected behavior.

Quitting Xcode nearly immediately fixes the problem, so it doesn't seem to be the simulations at fault here. My colleague also has her Mac occasionally heat up tremendously as well. Any idea why, and any solutions? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Didn't know whether to put this with the software recommendations, superuser.com, or here, but I thought this was the most appropriate place as it could be code related.

Comment: I have a similar problem. My Mac becomes incredibly slow. It’s the worst since I installed beta 7. Is this for you also the case?

Comment: @cbjeukendrup It's been doing this since before beta 7 for me, at this point since the final product will most likely be shipped by the 10th of September, it won't be much of a problem for much longer. It's just been a hassle to deal with.

Comment: In case it's still of use: I was running into similar problems (but on an iPhone) where my app started using 150mb of memory when using a `SwiftUI` view instead of 49mb using a more standard `UIKit` view. It turned out to be my over-use of `drawingGroup()` for every element in the display. When I removed every instance of this modifier then the memory use fell back down to around 59mb. In my case, this didn't affect performance so I was happy to lose the feature.